# Google Apps Scrit add value to array every time a loop executes

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I would like to add "RealData" to my array "tempArr", I am trying to use "push" but I have no experience with it so I can not get it to work. Could you help me out?

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var testDate =  subDaysFromDate(data[i][0],1)
   var DateToCheck = Utilities.formatDate(testDate, "GMT", "dd-MM-yyyy");
   var DateToCheckBefore = DateToCheck.split("-");
   var DateToCheckAfter = new Date(DateToCheckBefore[2], DateToCheckBefore[1]-1, DateToCheckBefore[0]); //dit is de datum van een row
   Row++; 

   var tempArr = new Array();

   var d1 = $d1.split("-");
   var d2 = $d2.split("-");

   var from = new Date(d1[0], d1[1]-1, d1[2]);  // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
   var to   = new Date(d2[0], d2[1]-1, d2[2]);

       if(DateToCheckAfter >= from && DateToCheckAfter <= to){
         var KlantNr = sheet.getRange("A"+Row).getValue();
         var KlantVoornaam = sheet.getRange("B"+Row).getValue();
         var KlantAchternaam = sheet.getRange("C"+Row).getValue();

         var HTMLData = KlantNr + "-" + KlantVoornaam + "-" + KlantAchternaam;
         var RealData = HTMLData.split("-");

         tempArr.push(RealData);

        }

  }
Logger.log(tempArr);
```

Comment: Firstly, don't initiate with the `new`, just use `var tempArr = []`, same with objects. Secondly, what's the current outcome and the expected one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you PUSH an array into another you're referencing it, to copy use slice:

```
tempArr.push(RealData.slice(0));
```

Also, this is a javascript problem.